# Visibilidad de elemento condicional en CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

Actualmente tengo un megamenú en WordPress controlado por un plugin, pero no permite que un subelemento contenga otro subelemento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, los elementos de la tercera columna (Circo -> Magia) serían subelementos de ARTISTAS, mientras que Cabalgata de Reyes Magos estática sería subelemento de CABALGATAS/NAVIDAD.

¿Es posible ocultar los resultados de la tercera y cuarta columna mediante CSS a no ser que el usuario ponga el ratón sobre la subcategoría padre?

```html
<li id="menu-item-11851" class="quadmenu-item-11851 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-tab quadmenu-item-has-children quadmenu-item-type-tab quadmenu-item-level-1 quadmenu-dropdown quadmenu-dropdown-submenu quadmenu-has-caret quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link dropdown-maxheight">
  <a href="#" class="quadmenu-dropdown-toggle hoverintent">
    <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                              <span class="quadmenu-caret"></span>
    <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">ESPECTÁCULOS</span>
    </span>
  </a>
  <div id="dropdown-11851" class="quadmenu_btt t_300 quadmenu-dropdown-menu">
    <ul class="quadmenu-row">
      <li id="menu-item-11863" class="quadmenu-item-11863 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-column quadmenu-item-has-children quadmenu-item-type-column col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div id="dropdown-11863" class="">
          <ul>
            <li id="menu-item-11866" class="quadmenu-item-11866 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-custom quadmenu-item-type-default quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">ARTISTAS</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11869" class="quadmenu-item-11869 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-custom quadmenu-item-type-default quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">CABALGATAS/NAVIDAD</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11874" class="quadmenu-item-11874 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/deportes/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">DEPORTES</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11875" class="quadmenu-item-11875 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/fuego/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">FUEGO</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11876" class="quadmenu-item-11876 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/gran-formato/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">GRAN FORMATO</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11877" class="quadmenu-item-11877 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/infantiles/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">INFANTILES</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11878" class="quadmenu-item-11878 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/mapping-dance/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">DANCE MAPPING</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11879" class="quadmenu-item-11879 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/musicales/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">MUSICALES</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11880" class="quadmenu-item-11880 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/pasacalles-itinerantes/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">PASACALLES / ITINERANTES</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11881" class="quadmenu-item-11881 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/teatros/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">TEATRO DE CALLE</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-11864" class="quadmenu-item-11864 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-column quadmenu-item-has-children quadmenu-item-type-column col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div id="dropdown-11864" class="">
          <ul>
            <li id="menu-item-11867" class="quadmenu-item-11867 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a rel="ARTISTAS" href="https://www.crearteevents.com/circo/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">Circo</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11868" class="quadmenu-item-11868 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/cocktail-artistico/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">Cocktel artístico</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11870" class="quadmenu-item-11870 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/danza/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">Danza</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11871" class="quadmenu-item-11871 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/dobles-de-famosos-2/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">Dobles de famosos</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11872" class="quadmenu-item-11872 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/magia/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">Magia</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-11865" class="quadmenu-item-11865 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-column quadmenu-item-has-children quadmenu-item-type-column col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div id="dropdown-11865" class="">
          <ul>
            <li id="menu-item-11873" class="quadmenu-item-11873 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/cabalgata-reyes-estatica/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">Cabalgata de Reyes Magos estática</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usaremos el símbolo `~` que se le conoce como [*Subsequent-sibling Combinator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) para poder activar un selector con otro.

Para esto usaremos la siguiente estructura general:

```
selectormenu1:hover ~ selectormenu2hastan{
}
```

donde `hover` es el evento de poner el mouse encima.

Usaremos el selector `:first-of-type` para seleccionar el primer elemento del tipo, en este caso tu menú de tercer nivel (ya que tus menús de siguiente nivel realmente son hermanos del mismo nivel en el HTML), y el selector `:not(:first-of-type)` para seleccionar los demás hermanos.

Si tuvieras que soportar [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer) te recomiendo usar en el padre `:first-child` y `:nth-child(n+2)` en lugar del `:not(algo)`.

```css
.quadmenu-item-level-3:first-of-type:hover~.quadmenu-item-level-3:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: block;
}

.quadmenu-item-level-3:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}

/*para que no desaparezca si se le pone el mouse encima*/
.quadmenu-item-level-3:not(:first-of-type):hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<li id="menu-item-11851" class="quadmenu-item-11851 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-tab quadmenu-item-has-children quadmenu-item-type-tab quadmenu-item-level-1 quadmenu-dropdown quadmenu-dropdown-submenu quadmenu-has-caret quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link dropdown-maxheight">
  <a href="#" class="quadmenu-dropdown-toggle hoverintent">
    <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                              <span class="quadmenu-caret"></span>
    <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">ESPECTÁCULOS</span>
    </span>
  </a>
  <div id="dropdown-11851" class="quadmenu_btt t_300 quadmenu-dropdown-menu">
    <ul class="quadmenu-row">
      <li id="menu-item-11863" class="quadmenu-item-11863 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-column quadmenu-item-has-children quadmenu-item-type-column col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div id="dropdown-11863" class="">
          <ul>
            <li id="menu-item-11866" class="quadmenu-item-11866 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-custom quadmenu-item-type-default quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                 <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">ARTISTAS</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11869" class="quadmenu-item-11869 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-custom quadmenu-item-type-default quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                  <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">CABALGATAS/NAVIDAD</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11874" class="quadmenu-item-11874 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/deportes/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                    <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">DEPORTES</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11875" class="quadmenu-item-11875 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/fuego/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">FUEGO</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11876" class="quadmenu-item-11876 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/gran-formato/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                 <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">GRAN FORMATO</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11877" class="quadmenu-item-11877 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/infantiles/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                 <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">INFANTILES</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11878" class="quadmenu-item-11878 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/mapping-dance/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                  <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">DANCE MAPPING</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11879" class="quadmenu-item-11879 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/musicales/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">MUSICALES</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11880" class="quadmenu-item-11880 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/pasacalles-itinerantes/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">PASACALLES / ITINERANTES</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11881" class="quadmenu-item-11881 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/teatros/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">TEATRO DE CALLE</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-11864" class="quadmenu-item-11864 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-column quadmenu-item-has-children quadmenu-item-type-column col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div id="dropdown-11864" class="">
          <ul>
            <li id="menu-item-11867" class="quadmenu-item-11867 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a rel="ARTISTAS" href="https://www.crearteevents.com/circo/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">Circo</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11868" class="quadmenu-item-11868 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/cocktail-artistico/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">Cocktel artístico</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11870" class="quadmenu-item-11870 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/danza/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">Danza</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11871" class="quadmenu-item-11871 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/dobles-de-famosos-2/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">Dobles de famosos</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11872" class="quadmenu-item-11872 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/magia/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">Magia</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-11865" class="quadmenu-item-11865 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-column quadmenu-item-has-children quadmenu-item-type-column col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div id="dropdown-11865" class="">
          <ul>
            <li id="menu-item-11873" class="quadmenu-item-11873 quadmenu-item quadmenu-item-object-page quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-type-post_type quadmenu-item-level-3 quadmenu-has-title quadmenu-has-link quadmenu-has-background quadmenu-dropdown-right">
              <a href="https://www.crearteevents.com/cabalgata-reyes-estatica/">
                <span class="quadmenu-item-content">
                                              <span class="quadmenu-text  hover t_1000">Cabalgata de Reyes Magos estática</span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
```